# How to allow service account from one name space to run pods in other name spaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have two namespaces: `n1` (for running EC2 instances) and `fargate` (connected to Fargate profile).
There is `data-processor` account in n1.
I'd like to allow data-processor account to run pods in `fargate` name space.

Now, I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://<cluster-id>.gr7.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/fargate/pods. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:n1:data-processor" cannot create resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "fargate".
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any of the roles or rolebindings so we can't see what permissions you have set already, but if you apply the following manifest it should work:

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: data-processor-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ['']
  resources: ['pods']
  verbs: ['get', 'watch', 'list', 'create', 'patch', 'update', 'delete']
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: data-processor-rolebinding
  namespace: fargate
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: data-processor
  namespace: n1
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: data-processor-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

That should allow your data-processor service account read/write permissions to pods in the fargate namespace.